# How can I use a custom font in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to use a custom font to mark certain features on a map. It needs to be defined as an attribute as the features in question are part of a unified text layer that includes various categories.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the layer properties and choose `Labels`. In 1.8 use the `Advanced` tab or if you have the development version `Data defined settings`. Then you can pick individual fields for the font family, size et cetera.

There was a large labelling rewrite after 1.8, so the new engine is by now better, but the old labelling should be good enough for this task too.

Comment: I gathered this much, but how does the naming work? If I have a font called "Blackletter Gothic Std" or similar can I just use that name as it appears in a normal font drop-down or...?

Comment: The dropdowns in that properties tab want the column name where the data is stored, but of course the font must be available on the system too. Most likely the naming should be like you said.